# am reinstalling flutter and I can't seem to run it, with PATH variables in the .bashrc and .zshrc all configured

Tags: linux, flutter, bash, zsh

I uninstalled flutter and wanted to install another new version of it, I might have deleted some files I wasn't supposed to, of changed permissions and never changed them back to how I found them.

here is the output when run "flutter doctor -v"

```
┌──(supr㉿3mp3r0r)-[/usr/sbin/flutter/bin]
└─$ sudo ./flutter doctor -v
[sudo] password for supr: 
   Woah! You appear to be trying to run flutter as root.
   We strongly recommend running the flutter tool without superuser privileges.
  /

[!] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.3, on Kali GNU/Linux Rolling 6.5.0-kali3-amd64, locale C.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 3.19.3 on channel stable at /usr/sbin/flutter
    ! The flutter binary is not on your path. Consider adding /usr/sbin/flutter/bin to your path.
    ! The dart binary is not on your path. Consider adding /usr/sbin/flutter/bin to your path.
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision ba39319843 (2 weeks ago), 2024-03-07 15:22:21 -0600
    • Engine revision 2e4ba9c6fb
    • Dart version 3.3.1
    • DevTools version 2.31.1
    • If those were intentional, you can disregard the above warnings; however it is recommended to use "git" directly to perform
      update checks and upgrades.

[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    • Android SDK at /root/Android/Sdk
    ✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.

[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    • Debian clang version 16.0.6 (16)
    • cmake version 3.27.7
    • ninja version 1.11.1
    • pkg-config version 1.8.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
    • Android Studio at /usr/bin/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.85.0)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Linux (desktop) • linux • linux-x64 • Kali GNU/Linux Rolling 6.5.0-kali3-amd64

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

I have changed the PATH variables from

```
/usr/sbin/flutter/bin/
```

to

```
/usr/sbin/flutter/bin
```

and sourced both shell configuration files .bashrc and .zshrc and still getting that same
'flutter doctor -v' output

Comment: Are the flutter and dart binaries present in /usr/sbin/flutter/bin?

Comment: Don't use /usr/sbin, prefer /usr/bin or even /home/yourUsername

Comment: I've never heard of `flutter` but in general with shell: sourcing both zsh and bash .rc files seems like it'd have potential to cause breakage, just source the one for the shell you use. The 2 PATH values you show are interchangeable but your PATH should generally contain a lot more directories than just that one. Maybe you did `PATH=/usr/sbin/flutter/bin` instead of `PATH=/usr/sbin/flutter/bin:$PATH` or similar by mistake?

Comment: You are running it via sudo, so I don't think **your** PATH is relevant. Therefore I would do two small tests: (1) Do a `sudo printenv PATH`. Does the path look right? (2) What happens if you drop the `sudo`? Still get the same message?