# flutter doctor -v not returning desired output log

Tags: linux, flutter, bash

when I run the commands

```
flutter doctor -v
```

is returning the output

```
Found an existing Pub cache at /home/supr/.pub-cache.
It can be repaired by running `dart pub cache repair`.
It can be reset by running `dart pub cache clean`
```

when I press Ctrl + C exiting the flutter doctor prompt
the entire output is a red text terminal of

```
Found an existing Pub cache at /home/supr/.pub-cache.
It can be repaired by running `dart pub cache repair`.
It can be reset by running `dart pub cache clean`.
Flutter failed to delete a directory at "/usr/sbin/flutter/.pub-preload-cache".
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.



#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
#1      _throwFileSystemException (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:831:3)
#2      _handlePosixException (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:761:3)
#3      _runSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:597:7)
#4      ErrorHandlingDirectory.deleteSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:478:12)
#5      _tryDeleteDirectory (package:flutter_tools/src/dart/pub.dart:40:17)
#6      _DefaultPub._preloadPubCache (package:flutter_tools/src/dart/pub.dart:619:7)
#7      _DefaultPub._getPubCacheIfAvailable (package:flutter_tools/src/dart/pub.dart:595:5)
#8      _DefaultPub._createPubEnvironment (package:flutter_tools/src/dart/pub.dart:681:30)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      _DefaultPub._runWithStdioInherited (package:flutter_tools/src/dart/pub.dart:356:48)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     _DefaultPub.get (package:flutter_tools/src/dart/pub.dart:323:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     PubDependencies.update (package:flutter_tools/src/flutter_cache.dart:126:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     Cache.updateAll (package:flutter_tools/src/cache.dart:715:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1699:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1389:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#15     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#16     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#17     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:355:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#18     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#19     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:295:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#20     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:119:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#21     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#22     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I reinstalled another version of flutter into path and was hoping to get the default normal output of the "flutter doctor" command but apprently that's what am getting and ending up with
and I can't seem to fix it for now.

Comment: Does you posting this new question mean you got a solution to [your previous problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78207181/am-reinstalling-flutter-and-i-cant-seem-to-run-it-with-path-variables-in-the)? If so you should post an answer to it there so others with the same problem in future can find it and benefit from it.

Comment: no am still having the same problem

Comment: Then you may want to respond to the comments there so we can make progress in trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

it ended up being an ownership and permission thing
I managed to fix it by going to the directory of flutter and

did change the permission by running the command

```
chown [USER]:root [FLUTTER DIRECTORY PATH]
```

and then everything just worked